# How to reference a model instance at a given point of time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a two-sided rental platform, where owner sets the price for their product freely. Whenever a renter creates a booking, I would need to lock in the snapshot of the `product` model so that sensitive information like `pricing` will be locked in for that rental. One thing I tried was just storing every information again at the `rental` model, but it seems very vulnerable to future changes and updates.

Is there a better way to overcome this problem?

--- edit, to make this more specific ---

So in my products table:

```
def change
  create_table :products do |t|
    t.integer :hourly_rate
    t.integer :daily_rate
  end
end
```

and in my rental_requests table, I need to have similar columns.

```
def change
  create_table :rental_requests do |t|
    t.integer :hourly_rate
    t.integer :daily_rate
  end
end
```

Which may cause problems when I have to update the columns in product, that means I have to update both tables.

Comment: Would it be possible to add another table Rate that can be referenced by Product and Rental_Request ???

Answer (score 0):

Your Product can have many Prices, and expose a `price` method which returns the latest Price. 
Rental can belong to Price.

Comment: At that moment when booking takes place, he wants to store that moment's fixed price. Reconsider your suggestion please.

Comment: @Elyasin: When the booking is created, the `rental` can reference the `price` exposed by the `product`, which will be that moment's fixed price.

Comment: @Elyasin: Assuming booking information is stored in `Rental`

Comment: Oh, yeah. I think I got it. OP should be more specific. The question might not belong on SO.